# Container not completely centered

Tags: html, css, border, responsive, center

I'm trying to build a random quote generator website and the quote container doesn't seem to be perfectly centered. You can notice that when resizing the page to a mobile device size. What line of code should I add to it to center it completely? I'll leave the snippet below so you can see for youself the issue. Many thanks in advance.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:wght@100&display=swap');

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #e1967b;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40' viewBox='0 0 40 40'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%23575658' fill-opacity='0.16'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 38.59l2.83-2.83 1.41 1.41L1.41 40H0v-1.41zM0 1.4l2.83 2.83 1.41-1.41L1.41 0H0v1.41zM38.59 40l-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L40 38.59V40h-1.41zM40 1.41l-2.83 2.83-1.41-1.41L38.59 0H40v1.41zM20 18.6l2.83-2.83 1.41 1.41L21.41 20l2.83 2.83-1.41 1.41L20 21.41l-2.83 2.83-1.41-1.41L18.59 20l-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L20 18.59z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L20 18.59z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  color: #000;
  font-family: Fraunces, san-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quote-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.quote-text {
    font-size: 2.75rem;
}

.long-quote {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-quote-left {
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.quote-author {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Media Query: tablet or smaller */

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .quote-container {
        margin: auto 10px;
    }
    .quote-text {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quote Generator</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="quote-container" id="quote-container">
        <!-- Quote -->
        <div class="quote-text">
            <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
            <span id="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Author -->
        <div class="quote-author">
            <span id="author">Buddha</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="button-container">
            <button class="twitter-button" id="twitter" title="Tweet quote">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            </button>
            <button id="new-quote">New Quote</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Script -->
    <i class="far fa-brain"></i>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's that stray `<i class="far fa-brain"></i>` at the very bottom of your HTML taking up one character of space.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, I totally forgot about that useless line of code, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***i tried it is now working. you will align it in the "qoute text" and the "long quote" and also you will have to change the with from auto to 500;
check the amendment below:***

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:wght@100&display=swap');

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #e1967b;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40' viewBox='0 0 40 40'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%23575658' fill-opacity='0.16'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 38.59l2.83-2.83 1.41 1.41L1.41 40H0v-1.41zM0 1.4l2.83 2.83 1.41-1.41L1.41 0H0v1.41zM38.59 40l-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L40 38.59V40h-1.41zM40 1.41l-2.83 2.83-1.41-1.41L38.59 0H40v1.41zM20 18.6l2.83-2.83 1.41 1.41L21.41 20l2.83 2.83-1.41 1.41L20 21.41l-2.83 2.83-1.41-1.41L18.59 20l-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L20 18.59z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L20 18.59z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  color: #000;
  font-family: Fraunces, san-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quote-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.quote-text {
    font-size: 2.75rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.long-quote {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.fa-quote-left {
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.quote-author {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Media Query: tablet or smaller */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .quote-container {
        margin: auto 10px;
    }
    .quote-text {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Quote Generator</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="quote-container" id="quote-container">
        <!-- Quote -->
        <div class="quote-text">
            <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
            <span id="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Author -->
        <div class="quote-author">
            <span id="author">Buddha</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="button-container">
            <button class="twitter-button" id="twitter" title="Tweet quote">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            </button>
            <button id="new-quote">New Quote</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Script -->
    <i class="far fa-brain"></i>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had a useless line of code which I've forgot about `<i class="far fa-brain"></i>`  and it was taking a character of space.